# How should we document the delegate methods in iOS using Doxygen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5, doxygen

Using Doxygen i have documented the methods declared by me and could generate documentation.

but i am looking for documenting the view life cycle methods and even delegate methods.

Can any one help me in achieving my requirement. All i am looking for is the equivalent documentation in doxygen as { @inherited } in javaDoc

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why is the documentation you have generated not valid?

Comment: I never said that the documentation I have generated is not valid.My question is what is the equivalent syntax of { @inherited }(javadoc) in Doxygen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-i/) It will give you an idea for what syntax to use for objective-c.

Edit: For docs on the View lifecycle, you would need to decide if you are doing anything outside of the ordinary that justifies needing comments(are you doing more than just updating data on viewwillappear).If you are can the code in those sections be broken out into another method (and then commented on the same as a normal method which would be my suggestion).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but in that site they have not explained about the view life cycle and delegate methods. I am expecting that